# Validate parameters before model binding for PUT request in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How do I distinguish between a parameter being sent as String.Empty and not being sent at all for my parameter binding for a PUT request.
  My request class looks like :

```
public class Person
{
   string name {get; set;}
   int? age {get; set;}
}
```

My problem is with binding 
When my user sends request as

```
{
   "name":"ABC"
}
```

In above mentioned case age parameter is mapped as null
However when request looks like below it maps to null as well. I would like to throw a validation error in below situation.
How do I achieve it in asp net core web api

```
{
   "name":"ABC",
   "age":""
}
```

Comment: Please try with this `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Person.age.ToString())` in a `if condition`, then show an error message.

Comment: @BasantaMatia I want to show an error only when input has empty string. With String.IsNullOrEmpty(Person.age.ToString()) it will throw validation error even when user has not passed the value at all

Comment: I'm not able to understand, you have already stated that in both the cases it's mapped to null. Then what's the issue ? You can check with the above code `if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Person.age))//error message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [DataAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api).

You can add the `Range` attribute on your nullable int. That will only allow integers or null, not empty strings.

```
public class Person
{
   string name {get; set;}
   [Range(0,300)]
   int? age {get; set;}
}
```

If the data annotations are not fullfilled it will set the modelstate to false

Then check the modelstate in the controller method

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // your logic

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
else
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
}
```